# One page will load the content base from the selected value of Drop Down List PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code

```
<select class="input form-control" id="Select" name="Select">
            <option value="Supplier">Supplier</option>
            <option value="User">User</option>
            <option value="Inventory">Inventory</option>
    </select>
```

and a button

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
```

i dont know how or what code that will load only my page base from the selected value from my drop down list.

Comment: Can you please let me know what exactly you want to do?

Comment: You need JQuery and AJAX for this

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax form submit

```
<div id="pagetoload"></div>
<form id="fid"  action="">
<select class="input form-control" id="Select" name="Select">
   <option value="Supplier">Supplier</option>
   <option value="User">User</option>
   <option value="Inventory">Inventory</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "mysubmitpage.php",
     data: $('#fid').serialize(), 
     success: function(response) {
        //Now here you can get back your html to append in page
        $('#pagetoload').html(response);
     },
    error: function() {
        alert("There was an error submitting form");
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with onchange event on the `select` tag.The will add with action attribute with selected value

```js
function actions(that){
document.getElementById('form').action=that.value
console.log(document.getElementById('form').action)
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <select class="input form-control" id="Select" name="Select" onchange="actions(this)">
 <option value="Supplier">Supplier</option>
 <option value="User">User</option>
 <option value="Inventory">Inventory</option>
</select>

  <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="this.form.submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If those pages are simple information page you can use JQuery click event to open that page as bellow.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {

    console.log($('#Select').val());
    if ($('#Select').val() == "Supplier") {
      window.open('Supplier.php');
    } else if ($('#Select').val() == "Inventory") {
      window.open('Inventory.php');
    } else if ($('#Select').val() == "User") {
      window.open('User.php');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <select class="input form-control" id="Select" name="Select">
 <option value="Supplier">Supplier</option>
 <option value="User">User</option>
 <option value="Inventory">Inventory</option>
</select>

  <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```